# Issue in Firmware Upload

Tags: arduino, esp32, usb-c, firmware, cp2102

I have a PCB with ESP32-Wroom32 module and CP2012N is used as USB to UART converter for Firmware upload via Arduino IDE. Issue is when I connect USB of PCB to my PC then my Task manager is not showing any port therefor i am unable to upload code in it. I am attaching the schematic of PCB. Can anyone tell me what can be possible issue in the design? I have tried many things like adding latest driver for CP2102N in my PC but I am still not able to figure out that issue is in PCB or in PC. I have even tried my laptop aswell but same issue is there, No COM port is shown in task manager[image]

Comment: Task manager? Do You mean Device manager? You mention CP2012N and CP2102N witch one? Be consistent. Do you hear the windows USB sound when plugging the device?

Comment: R20 pulls RSTb down to GND but it should pull up to VDD. SUSPENDb is an output, why connected to GND?

Comment: C9 is not mentioned in the datasheet of CP2102, I would remove it. EN of ESP32 needs 1-10 µF to GND and 10-75 kohm to +3V3 to boot.

Answer (score 1):

R20 is grounded. It should be connected to VDD. The CP2102N is being held in reset. I would also recommend using a 10k as your pull resistor.

As @Jens mentions SUSPENDb is an output. It should not be connected to ground. It can cause a dead short if the pin pulls high. Disconnect, if you are not using it.

[image]